# wordpress taxonomy results

Tags: posts, theme-development, loop, themes

I am using taxonomy.php to fetch some rows from database. On taxonomy page the function get_queried_object() shows that I have got the right results from database but wordpress loop `if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();` is looping over all rows from database. Does have_posts() always iterates over all rows in database?

Edit :

```
query_posts("post_type=taxonomy_name&posts_per_page=6");
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

Am i rewriting the query in query_posts()?

Edit :

if i remove the first line

```
query_posts("post_type=taxonomy_name&posts_per_page=6");
```

the loop is not printing any thing.

Comment: the loop displays whatever is in the global query object. the query for a taxonomy term happens before the template is loaded, i'll guess that you're creating a new query in the template with incorrect parameters and overwriting the default. edit your question to show us the contents of your taxonomy.php file.

Answer (score 0):

`have_posts()` iterates over all posts found and actually returned in the query which depend in the `posts_per_page` parameter.

And for your second question, using `query_posts()` does overwrite the query and its not really the recommend method to alter or modify the query result, here is a nice question that explains better ways :  [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)